# how to get element by component name in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the listing of a component in the DOM. Something like 
`document.getElementsByTagName("ComponentName")` but with a component name.

Comment: This might be a [xy-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). One of the advantages of React is that you don't have to deal with the DOM directly. Whatever problem you want to solve by doing this might have a simple and ideomatic solution in React itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Components aren't part of the DOM Model. As such, you cannot get a list of Components from the `document` object.

What you can do instead is to give the React Components you're interested in finding, a certain css class name, which you then can find in the DOM.

---

For example:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="myComponent">{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent>foo</MyComponent>
        <MyComponent>bar</MyComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));

/* get components from their class name: */
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("myComponent");
for (var item of list) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

You can of course also use `id` and use `document.getElementById()` (if the `id` is unique) or `name` and use `document.getElementsByName()`, and other methods. I think `class` makes most sense.